# Proteger con django la descarga de un fichero a determinado usuario en apache

Tags: django, apache

Quiero proteger un fichero que reside en un apache para que solo pueda descarglo si usuario que está logeado lo tiene permitido. El caso es que en el servidor de pruebas que trae django funciona sin problemas, pero no había caido que en Apache este plantemiento no parece válido y quisiera saber si hay alguna solución con este planteamiento.

La idea inicial es que un usuario suba un adjunto a una carpeta y solo lo pueda descargar ese mismo usuario.

Para ello tenemos el siguiente código:

```
urls.py
url(r'^documentos/prueba(?P<path>.*)$'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL[1:]), protected_serve_prueba),

views.py
@login_required
def protected_serve_prueba(request, path, document_root='documentos'):
    if _Una_condicion_cualquiera_ == request.user:
        return serve(request, 'prueba'+path, document_root)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Lo siento, no tiene permiso para acceder a ese archivo")
```

En la directiva del apache

```
Alias /documentos/prueba /var/www/prueba/documentos/prueba
```

En el momento que pongo la directiva en el apache ignora lo que pongo en urls.py y muestra el adjunto sin verificar si tiene o no permiso para ello.

¿Que soluciones se pueden tener a esto?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De momento he encontrado una solución que me sirve, aunque seguramente las haya mejores; la idea es quitar el Alias en el Apache, lo cual me bloquea las peticiones de descarga de forma directa por url.

Luego solo tenemos que coger el fichero desde la ruta que tengamos en el servidor y devolverlo como contenido adjunto en el response si el usuario cumple las condiciones que detallemos para acceder al fichero.

En mi caso solo se tratan ficheros pdf así que de momento sirve con cambiar en el views.py

```
@login_required
def protected_serve_prueba(request, path):
    if _Una_condicion_cualquiera_ == request.user:
        f = open(ruta_hasta_la_carpeta_adecualda+path, 'rb')
            response = HttpResponse(content=f)
            response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
            return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Lo siento, no tiene permiso para acceder a ese archivo")
```